# Is it possible to have sharper drawables when Android rescales them?

Tags: android, drawable, image-scaling

Let's say I have a bunch of drawables in the `mdpi` folder and I also need those in the `ldpi` folder. But I don't want to duplicate the image files in smaller sizes, **I would rather have Android rescale them as needed** (they don't look that bad and I have very few users on `ldpi`).

I tested this in my app and it works good enough. But I would prefer if the rescaled drawables were slightly sharper. Is there anyway I can enforce this behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. One doesn't have control over how Android resizes the missing resources.
For best quality drawables, You have to resize them yourself and put them on the according resource folder( -*dpi).